# How to access localhost:port by domain names

Tags: apache, portforwarding, hosts-file

I have localhost:8080 forwarded to mysite1.myhost1.com and localhost:9000 forwarded to mysite2.myhost2.com

I am able to access the websites by localhost:8080 and localhost:9000 resp.

What I want is I want to type mysite1.myhost1.com in browser and it should redirect to localhost:8080 ... that will in turn forward to real mysite1.myhost1.com... Similarly I want to type mysite2.myhost2.com in browser and it should redirect to localhost:9000 ... that will in turn forward to real mysite2.myhost1.com.

Is this possible?
I am using apache webserver
Please let me know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your solution would be using Apache's Reverse Proxy.

First you have to enable the Apache Proxy Module:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
```

By adding this to your Virtual Hosts file you can pass a request to a different backend server (for example localhost:8080):

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

If you also want to pass Websocket requests you can add the following below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Your final config will look similar to this (for mysite1.myhost1.com):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysite1.myhost1.com

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
        RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Remember that I used http over https in my example for simplicity, but https is the recommended way.

Comment: Will try this solution and let you know. Thanks.